# Is it possible to return a class (but not an instance of a class) in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

relatively new programmer here. 
Look at the two classes defined below. I'd like to be able to call the following:

```
[instanceOfSecondClass transitionToPage: [instanceOfFirstClass nextPage]];
```

However, that doesn't seem to work (because I'm trying to return a class, not an instance of a class.)

```
@implementation FirstClass
- (id)nextPage {
    return SomeOtherClass;
}
@end


@implementation SecondClass
- (void)transitionToPage:(id)someOtherClass {
    currentPageViewController = [[mySomeOtherClass alloc] init];
    ...
}
@end
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do here?

Sometimes things that make sense to me totally don't make sense in the real world :).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Class" is the type you want to return

```
@implementation MyClass
- (Class)nextPage {
     return [SomeOtherClass class];
}
@end
```

Hope it works,
ief2

Comment: Excellent! I knew it was possible, I just couldn't quite figure out the syntax.